# Selected in Option pass to click function

Tags: jquery

I have 2 text box and 1 Drop down. I want is to get the value of the selected select and redirect based on it. How can I pass the language value in button click event?

The value of dropdown is en_US and ja_JP
My error is undefined language

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
       //get selected option 
        $('.bfh-selectbox').on('change.bfhselectbox', function () {
           var currentlanguage = $(this).val();
        });



        $("#btn-signin").click(function() {
        //alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
        var user = $('#username').val();
        var pass = $('#password').val();
        var currentlanguage = "";


       if(user == "admin" && pass == "admin" && currentlanguage == "ja_JP") 
       {
       window.location = "http://localhost/neoDIME/ja/dashboard-staff.html";
       }
       else {
        window.location = "http://localhost/neoDIME/dashboard-staff.html";;
      }

      });
     });
```

Comment: while you've just 1 dropdown no need to pass it .. just use `currentlanguage  = $('.bfh-selectbox').val()` .. and no need for `.change()` event unless you'll use it to make some action